# Getting null output when schema specified to read data in BigQuery select operation

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am facing issue when selecting data from BigQuery table with specified schema.

```
val tableData:RDD[String] = sqlContext.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
hadoopConf,
classOf[GsonBigQueryInputFormat],
classOf[LongWritable],
classOf[JsonObject]).map(_._2.toString)

val jsonSchema:StructType = (new StructType).add("f1",IntegerType,true).add("f2",FloatType,true).add("f3",StringType,true).add("f4",BooleanType,true).add("f5",DateType,true).add("f6",TimestampType,true)

val df = sqlContext.read.schema(jsonSchema).json(tableData)
```

When I specify schema like above I am getting null result in the data frame.But when no schema specified getting proper results.

```
df.printSchema()

root
|-- f1: integer (nullable = true)
|-- f2: float (nullable = true)
|-- f3: string (nullable = true)
|-- f4: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- f5: date (nullable = true)
|-- f6: timestamp (nullable = true)

 df.show
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| f1| f2| f3| f4| f5| f6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|null|null|null|
```

When analyzed I found BigQuery exports table data in following format ex:

`{"f1":"3","f2":2.7,"f3":"Anna","f4":true,"f5":"2014-10-15","f6":"2014-10-15 03:15:58 UTC"}`.

When I read from tableData using json format it can't cast the data with specified schema and returns null result.

How can I get proper result with specified schema? Please suggest if you have any idea/solution for it.

Comment: you should try exporting data from big query and importing in spark environment.